# Mule ESB download file from URL string

Tags: esb, mule

So, using Mule ESB, I'm searching Bing for certain PDF files. Then I'm parsing the JSON response to capture the URL of the file location. Now I need to retrieve the file and save locally. Below is what I have so far, but I have a feeling I'm going about this all wrong. How can I complete the use case?

I'm having two problems:

1) Can't figure out how to strip "http" from #[message.payload.Url] (since the HTTP Endpoint adds http to the url I'm passing in.

2) Can't figure out how to retrieve the file. I don't even know if HTTP Endpoint is the right option. HTTP? File?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
    <flow name="BingFlow1" doc:name="BingFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="api.datamarket.azure.com" port="443" path="Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27contract%20california%27&amp;WebFileType=%27PDF%27&amp;$top=50&amp;$format=Json" user="********" password="*****" doc:name="Bing"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.d.results]" doc:name="Expression"/>
        <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="#[message.payload.Url]" port="80" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/home/user/Documents/output" outputPattern="#[message.payload.ID].pdf" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't test the flow because some credentials are needed but the following should help you:

- Use an `expression-transformer` to strip the HTTP out,
- Your approach with an `http:outbound-endpoint` followed by a `file:outbound-endpoint` will work fine,
- Change the `http:inbound-endpoint` to `one-way`: there is no way to return anything sensible since the execution flow gets split.

For example, assuming `message.payload.Url` resolves to a `java.lang.String`, you can use:

```
<expression-transformer expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.substringAfter(message.payload.Url, 'http://')]" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

Comment: Awesome. I just changed the inbound-endpoint to one-way. I was returning to the rest client, but you're right...I have it echoing to the console, so no real need.

Comment: How would you write the expression, I added `<expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.Url]" doc:name="Expression"/>` after the collection-splitter, but I'm not sure how to strip the http:// from the URL. Can you provide an example or even documentation showing how to accomplish that? I'm not seeing it in the Mule docs.

Comment: No particular doc for that: this is MEL (built on http://mvel.codehaus.org) which gives you access to any Java object, including in this case `org.mule.util.StringUtils` useful for dealing with Strings. I reviewed my answer accordingly.

Comment: What about using Script Component to just do string manipulation? I'm just not seeing exactly how to use the expression-transformer without writing a java class.

Comment: No need at all for a Script component to do this. You could use the expression transformer without the use of a helper class (but **why**?) by using the `substring` and `indexOf` methods of `java.lang.String`.

Comment: I'm sorry for being such a noob with Mule. I'm so used to using Pentaho & WSO2. Very different approaches. So, I know my object references is `#[message.payload.Url]`. What evaluator & expression would I want to use to just strip the "http://" from the beginning of the string at that reference?

Comment: Thank you for your help on this...I also posted another problem toward the end of the flow at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982760/mule-file-download-with-http-endpoint