# Mule file download with HTTP Endpoint

Tags: mule

My HTTP Endpoint responsible for downloading the file at the end of the flow is erroring out. It keeps trying to communicate with `http://:80/` instead of the URL passed in. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd ">
    <flow name="BingFlow1" doc:name="BingFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="api.datamarket.azure.com" port="443" path="Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27contract%20california%27&amp;WebFileType=%27PDF%27&amp;$top=50&amp;$format=Json" user="*****" password="*****" doc:name="Bing"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.d.results]" doc:name="Expression"/>
        <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
        <expression-transformer expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.substringAfter(message.payload.Url, 'http://')]" doc:name="Expression"/>
        <logger message="Payload is: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.substringBefore(message.payload, '/')]" port="80" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/pdf" mimeType="application/pdf" path="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.substringAfter(message.payload, '/')]"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.replace(message.payload, '/','.')]" path="/home/user/Documents/output" mimeType="application/pdf"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

When changed to match the first answer, I get this exception:

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke REST service "http://santaclaraca.gov/modules/ShowDocument.aspx?documentid=108?followRedirects=true". Message payload is of type: LinkedHas
hMap
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Failed to invoke REST service "http://santaclaraca.gov/modules/ShowDocument.aspx?documentid=108?followRedirects=true". Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap (org.mule.transp
ort.http.components.RestServiceException)
  org.mule.transport.http.components.RestServiceWrapper:219 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/http/components/RestServiceException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.transport.http.components.RestServiceException: Failed to invoke REST service "http://santaclaraca.gov/modules/ShowDocument.aspx?documentid=108?followRedirects=true". Mess
age payload is of type: LinkedHashMap
    at org.mule.transport.http.components.RestServiceWrapper.doInvoke(RestServiceWrapper.java:219)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:126)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:61)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

**--- SOLVED ---**

Big thanks to David. This is my final solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
    xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">

    <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
        <expression-language>
            <import class="org.mule.util.StringUtils" />
        </expression-language>
    </configuration>
    <flow name="BingQuery" doc:name="BingQuery">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="api.datamarket.azure.com" port="443"
            path="Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27california%20school%20district%20contract%27&amp;WebFileType=%27PDF%27&amp;$top=10&amp;$format=Json"
            user="*****" password="*****"
            doc:name="Bing" />
        <json:json-to-object-transformer
            returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
        <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.d.results]"
            doc:name="Expression" />
        <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter" />
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            doc:name="VM" path="fileWriter" />
    </flow>
    <flow name="RestProcessor" doc:name="RestProcessor">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            doc:name="VM" path="fileWriter" />
        <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="#[message.payload.ID].pdf"
            doc:name="Variable" />
        <http:rest-service-component
            serviceUrl="#[joinChar=message.payload.Url.contains('?')?'&amp;':'?' ; StringUtils.join(new String[]{message.payload.Url,(String)joinChar,'followRedirects=true'})]"
            httpMethod="GET">
            <http:error-filter>
                <expression-filter
                    expression="#[Integer.valueOf(message.inboundProperties['http.status']) &gt;= 400]"></expression-filter>
            </http:error-filter>
        </http:rest-service-component>
        <file:outbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000"
            doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[flowVars.fileName]" path="/home/ken/Documents/output"
            mimeType="application/pdf" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: What gets logged after: "Payload is:" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't spot the error: your flow looks good (except a problem I'll detail below) so, alternatively to using an `http:outbound-endpoint`, which can be finicky at times, you could use the `http:rest-service-component`.

Your next problem will be in the `outputPattern` of the file endpoint: remember at this point `message.payload` will be the response from the HTTP endpoint not the (partial) URL anymore. You need to pre-compute the file name and store it in a flow variable, then use it.

This would give:

```
<configuration>
  <expression-language>
    <import class="org.mule.util.StringUtils" />
  </expression-language>
</configuration>

<flow name="BingFlow1" doc:name="BingFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="api.datamarket.azure.com" port="443" path="Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27contract%20california%27&amp;WebFileType=%27PDF%27&amp;$top=50&amp;$format=Json" user="*****" password="*****" doc:name="Bing"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.d.results]" doc:name="Expression"/>
    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
    <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.substringAfter(message.payload.Url, 'http://').replace('/','.')]" />
    <http:rest-service-component serviceUrl="#[joinChar=message.payload.Url.contains('?')?'&amp;':'?' ; StringUtils.join(new String[]{message.payload.Url,(String)joinChar,'followRedirects=true'})]" httpMethod="GET">
        <http:error-filter>
            <expression-filter expression="#[Integer.valueOf(message.inboundProperties['http.status']) &gt;= 400]" />
        </http:error-filter>
    </http:rest-service-component>
    <file:outbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[flowVars.fileName]" path="/home/user/Documents/output" mimeType="application/pdf"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Awesome solution, but rest-service-component doesn't do followRedirects? I'll try to filter out anything that doesn't end in .pdf and see if that works. It's dying on the 3rd result because it is a redirect to the pdf.

Comment: Oh no problem: `rest-service-component` is configured by default to reject anything not 20x, let me see if I can find the config to follow redirects.

Comment: OK reviewed my answer to support redirects. Note I have also globally imported `org.mule.util.StringUtils` in MEL to lighten up the syntax a little.

Comment: I edited my question to show the exception I'm getting. This time I got 6 files though. More than before.

Comment: Aaw I see: the URL has a query param in it so my naive appending of `?followRedirects=true` breaks it. The expression must be reviewed to append either `?` or `&`.

Comment: For some reason it is erroring out on a 404. Isn't that what the http:error-filter handles?

Comment: `org.mule.transport.http.components.RestServiceException: Failed to invoke REST service "http://publicportal.ousd.k12.ca.us/199410811175930900/lib/199410811175930900/OEA_Contract_05
-08_-_COMPLETE_Contract.pdf?followRedirects=true". Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap`

Comment: 404 is detected as an error so that is normal (the default `error-filter` was detecting anything >2xx as an error, including redirects)

Comment: Right, but right now it is set to detect anything that is >= 400 and Mule is erroring out on 404. Shouldn't it ignore 404 and just move on to the next message?

Comment: The filter detects anything >=400 as an error so 404 is detected as an error: this is why the exception is thrown. Mule should keep processing the other HTTP requests independently of this exception: isn't that the case?

Comment: It doesn't seem to. I have 10 results I'm looping through right now (even though the sample above shows 50). I manually checked the 10 results and only 1 of the 10 is returning something other than a 200 or 300 series result. That one is returning 404 (expected). When I look into my `output` folder after the process has been running for a while, I'm getting only 6 files. My guess is that it is stopping the process once it hits the 404 instead of continuing to process everything else.

Comment: That's strange but not impossible: try cutting the flow in two flows right after the splitter. Connect them with a one way VM endpoint. This should isolate failures.