# Get file behind html form

Tags: mule

I have a file I want to download. The file is secured with a html form:

[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXC7I.png)
I want to download the following URL to the Payload: https://10.10.0.18/history/information.csv

What function do I use in Mule and is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

For Basic authentication with only username and password, you can use HTTP request connector followed by a file outbound endpoint
Refer  :-  
 https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Authentication+in+HTTP+Requests

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Authentication+in+HTTP+Requests#AuthenticationinHTTPRequests-basic

You can also look the following reference :- [Mule ESB download file from URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945051/mule-esb-download-file-from-url-string)